# NVIDIA drivers as LKMs in Unix: Module nvidia not found

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, nvidia

Some time ago, I installed GeForce GTX 970 on my computer running under Fedora 20. An import thing to know is that I'm using the card only as an accelerator (not for graphics). Until recently, it worked fine. But then I've faced the following problem when trying to launch a `.cu` executable:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found.
bug.cu (16): no CUDA-capable device is detected in cudaMalloc((void **)&p, sizeof(int))
```

I've googled for similar cases and found out that the message can be interpreted as inability of `modprobe` (who manages so called linkable kernel modules) to find one particular LKM - nvidia or, to put it even more simpler, there is something wrong with drivers.

Then I investigated that further in the following way:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 3171
Kernel modules: nouveau
```

On a forum I've read that two more NVidia LKM exist (and, possibly, should be present in the above given output): `nvidia` and `nvidiafb` which, as you can see, are missing in my system.

And here's my question: does that necessarily mean, that I don't have these modules at all? Or it might be the case that they don't have to be there all the time and get linked to the kernel only when necessary?

Should I reinstall my drivers? Or probably those modules simply got disabled somehow and I should just activate it in a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by reinstalling the drivers.

First I tried to reinstall it with `yum` (because it was initially installed in this way) but that didn't help. So I removed it and downloaded drivers from NVidia [official cite](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us). Installation was done according to [this](http://linuxconfig.org/nvidia-geforce-driver-installation-on-fedora-linux-64-bit) instruction.

After that everything worked. As for LKMs:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 3171
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```